# How do I insert a JPEG image into a python Tkinter window?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, window, jpeg

How do I insert a JPEG image into a Python 2.7 Tkinter window? What is wrong with the following code? The image is called *Aaron.jpg*.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Image
import Tkinter
window = Tkinter.Tk()

window.title("Join")
window.geometry("300x300")
window.configure(background='grey')

imageFile = "Aaron.jpg"

window.im1 = Image.open(imageFile)


raw_input()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: How long have you spent on this?

Comment: Umm... what's the ext for?

Comment: Probably unnecessary to say this... "Please fix the code and paste it below!"

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Check [this](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm) out & see if problem persists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an image in Tkinter (Python 2.7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133856/how-to-add-an-image-in-tkinter-python-2-7)

Comment: @dilbert over six years (:

Answer (score 60):

Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

#This creates the main window of an application
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Join")
window.geometry("300x300")
window.configure(background='grey')

path = "Aaron.jpg"

#Creates a Tkinter-compatible photo image, which can be used everywhere Tkinter expects an image object.
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))

#The Label widget is a standard Tkinter widget used to display a text or image on the screen.
panel = tk.Label(window, image = img)

#The Pack geometry manager packs widgets in rows or columns.
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

#Start the GUI
window.mainloop()
```

Related docs: [ImageTk Module](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagetk.htm), [Tkinter Label Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm), [Tkinter Pack Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm)

Comment: Note that the original PIL won't work with Python 3, but Pillow is pretty much a drop-in replacement: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Re @Caspar's comment, at command line for Python 3(.6), do `pip install pillow` to get the module.

Comment: As a note, additional "popup" windows that contain images need the image to be specified outside of Label instantiation as well (e.g. `label = tk.Label(window, image=img)` then `label.image = img` before finally `label.pack()`)

Answer (score 1):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image,  ImageTk
win = tk. Tk()
image1 = Image. open("Aoran. jpg")
image2 =  ImageTk. PhotoImage(image1)
image_label = ttk. Label(win , image =.image2)
image_label.place(x = 0 , y = 0)
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -3):

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

window = Tk()
window.geometry("1000x300")

path = "1.jpg"

image = PhotoImage(Image.open(path))

panel = Label(window, image = image)

panel.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as to wat is hapng here