# Ipython notebook dead kernel from image insert in Tkinter window using PIL

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library, jupyter-notebook

I have tried for several days to get an image displaying using the following code.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

#This creates the main window of an application
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Join")
window.geometry("300x300")
window.configure(background='grey')

path = "Aaron.jpg"

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))


panel = tk.Label(window, image = img)

#The Pack geometry manager packs widgets in rows or columns.
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

#Start the GUI
window.mainloop()
```

The code is originally from this link.

[How do I insert a JPEG image into a python Tkinter window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901168/how-do-i-insert-a-jpeg-image-into-a-python-tkinter-window)

When I run the code with my own path I get the following error messages

Python quit unexpectedly warning

and then:

The kernel appears to have died.  It will restart automatically.

System info

Mac OS X Version 10.7.5
Anaconda
ipython-notebook version 3.2.1
Python 2.7.10-0
PIL 1.1.7 
pillow 2.9.0

This is my first question on stackoverflow so please excuse any formatting errors.  I will try to correct if there is an issue.  I've also tried many version of code that is similar with the same result.  This only happens with this specific code.