# an error occured to add picture in python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, python-3.5

I am new in python and I am using python 3.5 version. I want to add photo to python, and here's the code I wrote:

```
from tkinter import *
win=Tk()
win.title("Python Image")

canvas=Canvas(win,width=500,height=500)
canvas.pack()

my_image=PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg")
canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor=NW,image=my_image)


win.mainloop()
```

But when I run it, the following error occurred:

```
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
================ RESTART: C:\Users\LABE-2\Desktop\rakibul.py ================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LABE-2\Desktop\rakibul.py", line 8, in <module>
    my_image=PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg")
  File "C:\Users\LABE-2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3539, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\LABE-2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3495, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"
>>>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I insert a JPEG image into a python Tkinter window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901168/how-do-i-insert-a-jpeg-image-into-a-python-tkinter-window)

Answer (score 0):

Photoimage can natively only load `png` and `pgm&ppm` images (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm).

You can load other image formats via [PIL](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/pil-index.htm). For python3 use [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) like this:

```
from PIL  import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Tk,Canvas,NW
win=Tk()
win.title("Python Image")

canvas=Canvas(win,width=500,height=500)
canvas.pack()

# use your path here ...
my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r"some.jpg"))
canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor=NW,image= my_image )

win.mainloop()
```

You could have found all this information in [NorthCats answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23905585/7505395) to  [How do I insert a JPEG image into a python Tkinter window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901168/how-do-i-insert-a-jpeg-image-into-a-python-tkinter-window) as well.