# How do i insert an image without using the PIL module?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
LH=Label(LowerHeading, font=('arial',12,'bold'), text ="Update", bd = 10, width = 15, anchor = 'w')
LH.grid(row=1,column=0)
path = 'C:/Users\Ermira1\Documents\Ermira\1. Sixth Form\Year 13\Computer Science/dress.jpg'
photo = PhotoImage(file="path")
LeftLower= Frame(text=photo)
```

For some reason this doesnt work and im not sure why.

The error message is displayed below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ermira1\Documents\Ermira\1. Sixth Form\Year 13\Computer Science\Inventory (new).py", line 163, in <module>
    photo = PhotoImage(file="path")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3416, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3372, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "path": no such file or directory
>>>
```

Comment: `r'C:/Users\Ermira1\Documents\Ermira\1. Sixth Form\Year 13\Computer Science/dress.jpg'`  - third question I see today, trying to use tkinter and `.jpg` - why not with PIL?  PhotoImage is not suited to work with jpg as is :http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I insert a JPEG image into a python Tkinter window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901168/how-do-i-insert-a-jpeg-image-into-a-python-tkinter-window)

Comment: read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49094370/7505395

Comment: How do i download the PIL module?

Comment: I dont mean to offend you but can you please show me how to edit my code to make sure it works @PatrickArtner

Comment: Look closely at the error message. It's telling you there's no such file named `"path"`. Pay attention to the last part -- it's looking for a file with the literal name `"path"` (_not_ with the name _stored_ in the variasble `path`). Though, fix that and you have two more problems: the backslashes don't do what you think they do, and `PhotoImage` doesn't support .jpg.

Comment: Then what do you recommend me to do?

Answer (score 2):

The immediate error is that you're trying to get an image from a place called `"path"`, which is by no means a path, you probably meant `path`.

```
photo = PhotoImage(file=path)
```

Which would *then* produce another error as the string that is `path` is erroneous as well, it uses `\` and `/` inconsistently; and since `\` is an escape character to modify the string in certain ways you should either be replacing them with double (`\\`) to escape the escape character itself, or use raw string format `r"my string such as path"`. So replace with either:

```
path = r'C:\Users\Ermira1\Documents\Ermira\1. Sixth Form\Year 13\Computer Science\dress.jpg'
```

or:

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\Ermira1\\Documents\\Ermira\\1. Sixth Form\\Year 13\\Computer Science\\dress.jpg'
```

---

> [*"How to insert an image without using the PIL module?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48512362/7032856)

First of all, you *can't* do that without using an additional library(be it 
[pil](/questions/tagged/pil) or something else) unless the format is supported by [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter)(.jpg, for example, *isn't* supported by the library).

Secondly, an image can be inserted in a number of ways, for the sake of clarity let's use a label to display.

The code below first downloads images(can be replaced entirely if the images already exist), then it tries to display a .png (it is supported in the versions of [tk](/questions/tagged/tk) later than 8.6), if it can't display .png then it tries to display .gif:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def download_images():
    # In order to fetch the image online
    try:
        import urllib.request as url
    except ImportError:
        import urllib as url
    url.urlretrieve("https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgD2r.png", "lenna.png")
    url.urlretrieve("https://i.stack.imgur.com/sML82.gif", "lenna.gif")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    download_images()
    root = tk.Tk()
    widget = tk.Label(root, compound='top')
    widget.lenna_image_png = tk.PhotoImage(file="lenna.png")
    widget.lenna_image_gif = tk.PhotoImage(file="lenna.gif")
    try:
        widget['text'] = "Lenna.png"
        widget['image'] = widget.lenna_image_png
    except:
        widget['text'] = "Lenna.gif"
        widget['image'] = widget.lenna_image_gif
    widget.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You did a much better job with the example, deleted mine. +1