# No file or Directory exist, but it does

Tags: python, file, tkinter

I am trying to use tkinter module to open a window to show a picture and was previously having trouble with: [_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094829/tkinter-tclerror-couldnt-recognize-data-in-image) 
I have since used the following this question to restructured my code to the following:
[How do I insert a JPEG image into a python Tkinter window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901168/how-do-i-insert-a-jpeg-image-into-a-python-tkinter-window)
I have made a few changes to the code as I am using python 3.
When I have tried to execute the code: I get an error saying no file or directory exist. However i have used the following code to check:
[python open() method IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201928/python-open-method-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory) 
Below are the result of checking the files:

```
 >>> os.listdir()
['comments.py', 'Conan.txt', 'conditions.py', 'dateandtime.py', 'desktop.ini', 'dictionaries.py', 'exceptions.py', 'forging_functions.py', 'formatting.py', 'graphics.py', 'Hello.py', 'leapdays.py', 'logging.py', 'loop.py', 'modules.py', 'months.py', 'numbers.py.py', 'Opening_files.py', 'Picture.jpg', 'print_hello.py.py', 'tkintercode1.py', 'tkintercode2.py', 'user_input.py', 'Writing_file.py', '__pycache__']
  >>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Users\\Draco\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Programming'
 >>> os.chdir(r'C:\\Users\\Draco\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Programming')
 >>> open('Picture.jpg')
 <_io.TextIOWrapper name='Picture.jpg' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

Below is the code I am working with:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Random Image")
window.geometry("300x300")
window.configure(background='grey')

path = "C:\Draco\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\Picture.jpg" 


img = tkinter.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
panel = tk.Label(window, image = img)

panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

window.mainloop()
```

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Please show the exact error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Draco\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\tkintercode2.py", line 12, in <module>
    img = open(path)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Draco\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Programming\\Picture.jpg'

Comment: this is the error that I am getting but I have checked to see if python recognise's the path, which it seem to so, but when I execute it I get the above error message

Comment: Also I've got rid of the tkinter.PhotoImage(Image. and let that bit of code as path = open(path)

Answer (score 1):

`"C:\Draco\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\Picture.jpg"`
 try `path  ="C:\\Draco\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Programming\\Picture.jpg"` - double slash
EDIT
You have diff in paths. Users\Draco but in code just Draco

Comment: I have tried that unfortunately that has worked, still the same error message