# Why Isn't My Image Showing With Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter, jpeg

[Following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901168/how-do-i-insert-a-jpeg-image-into-a-python-tkinter-window), I am trying to get an image to display, yet when I go and run it (nearly exactly as it is in the answer), the window doesn't display the image.

```
from PIL import Image
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Join")
window.geometry("300x300")
window.configure(background='grey')
imageFile = "/Users/glennsha/Desktop/APCS_Create/Rank_icons/champion1.jpg"
window.im1 = Image.open(imageFile)

input()
window.mainloop()
```

[image: Why is it not displaying?]

Comment: You copied the question format but did not use `img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))` as in the answer for that question. Try adding this portion to your code as well as adding the actually image widget to the frame.

Comment: So, you removed code from a working example and now it's not working? Did you consider that maybe you removed some important pieces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23905585/5722359) in the same link you have quoted.
I have added explanations to the relevant sections to help your understanding. You can read more about `Image` and `ImageTk` [here](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm).

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk # I have added the import of ImageTk 
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Join")
window.geometry("300x300")
window.configure(background='grey')
imageFile = "/Users/glennsha/Desktop/APCS_Create/Rank_icons/champion1.jpg"

#Creates a Tkinter-compatible photo image, which can be used everywhere Tkinter expects an image object.
im1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imageFile))

#Next, you need to put your image into a widget before it can be visible.
# Your reference answer used a Label widget. We will use the same here.
# This Label widget is a child of "window" which is the Tk() window. 
panel = tkinter.Label(window, image = im1)

#Next you need to put the widget into the Tk() window before the widget can be made visible.
# Here, the Pack geometry manager is used to put/locate the widget containing
# the images into the Tk() Window.
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should edit out your file path and leave the OPs file path. No reason to show both.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Thanks for reminding. Used it for testing. Forgot to remove.