# Only one image appeared in the window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import random

win = tk.Tk()
win.title('Country game')
win.geometry('2800x2800')

countries = ['Australia.png','Brazil.png','China.png','Egypt.png','France.png','Germany.png',
             'Italy.png','Spain.png','UK.png']
random.shuffle(countries)

for country in countries:
    img = Image.open(country)
    landmark = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    btn = tk.Button(win,image=landmark)
    btn.image = landmark
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            btn.grid(row=i,column=j)
```

For this program, it does not show any error messages. However my aim is to place the nine images randomly on the tkinter window, but when I run this program only one image button did appear. Although I used two for loops to grid other eight ones do not appear. May I ask what is the best method to place nine images for 3 rows and 3 images per row?

Comment: You need to open the image first .Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/23905585/12870513

Comment: You also need to keep a reference for them.

Comment: I do not know how to keep a reference

Comment: say `btn.image = landmark`

Comment: @Dom807 `btn.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")` I tried replacing all your for loops with this and it works fine..Your `btn.place` is not working

Comment: Image can be shown but I would like to show 9 images in a window for 3 rows and each row 3 images

Comment: You are calling `grid` to place the same button in nine different locations. Why are you doing that? Are you aware a button can only appear in one place at a time?

Comment: @BryanOakley what if it was a label?

Comment: @CoolCloud: a widget can only appear in one place at a time no matter what type it is.

Comment: @BryanOakley But if i was to call a loop on same button widget, but `grid()` it in a straight line, i get 9 buttons with images

Comment: The title of this question says "no images appear" but the body says "only one image button did appear". Can you please clarify?

Comment: I don't know whether btn is the same button or nine different buttons as I put it in the loop ```for country in countries:```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looping over nine images, and for each of those nine images you are calling  `grid` nine times, for a total of 81 calls to `grid`. And, since only the last call to grid for any single button is the only one that has an effect, all nine buttons are ultimately ending up at row 2, column 2. That is why you see a single button. They are all there, but they are all at the same location.

You don't need to iterate over the list of countries *and* the rows and columns. Instead, just iterate over the rows and columns and pull the next image from the randomized list of images:

```
random.shuffle(countries)
for row in range(3):
    for column in range(3):
        image_file = countries.pop()
        img = Image.open(image_file)
        landmark = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        btn = tk.Button(win,image=landmark)
        btn.image = landmark
        btn.grid(row=row, column=column)
```

Comment: But may I ask why need to use ```countries.pop()```?

Comment: what about `countries = iter(countries)` and then using `image_file = next(countries)` ?

Comment: @Dom807: why use `countries.pop()`? No particular reason. It's just a convenient way to pull each item out of the list. Yes, you can use `iter(countries)`.