# Python3 tkinter: showing images from the Internet on a label (urllib) does not work

Tags: image, tkinter, base64, urllib

I would like to show Images from the Internet in a Label. I can do it with Images from the harddisk. Then I looked for a way to do it with Photos from the Internet and I wrote the following code:

```
    self.res = requests.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
    print(self.res)
    self.jason = json.loads(self.res.content)
    print (self.jason)
    bild = self.jason['message']
    print (bild)
    u = urllib.request.urlopen(bild)
    raw_data = u.read()
    u.close()
    b64_data = base64.encodestring(raw_data)
    image = tk.PhotoImage(data = b64_data)
    self.pic_label["image"] = image
```

But I get the following error message:

```
*Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "/home/wolfgang/Eigene Programme/python_buch/api.py", line 42, in api
image = tk.PhotoImage(data = b64_data)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3545, in __init__
Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3501, in __init__
self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize image data*
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

P.S.: I am using Linux, if that should matter.

Update:

In the meanwhile I updated my function. But it still doesn't show images. Does it maybe have to do with the api? Any ideas what I have to change?

```
def api(self):
    

    self.res = requests.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
    print(self.res)
    self.jason = json.loads(self.res.content)
    print (self.jason)
    bild = self.jason['message']
    image_bytes = urllib.request.urlopen(bild).read()
    data_stream = io.BytesIO(image_bytes)
    pil_image = Image.open(data_stream)
    tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
    
    self.anzeige = tk.Label(self.root,image=tk_image)
    self.anzeige.pack()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code it returned a jpg image. The `tkinter.PhotoImage` class doesn't directly support jpg. You'll need to use PIL/Pillow to create the image and hand it off to tkinter, or use some other library to convert it to png or gif before creating a `PhotoImage`.

For how to display jpeg images in tkinter see [How do I insert a JPEG image into a python Tkinter window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901168/how-do-i-insert-a-jpeg-image-into-a-python-tkinter-window)