# Is .png the only format acceptable in python's tkinter module?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, photoimage, tkinter-photoimage

I tried inserting a picture with format .jpg as a PhotoImage

But everytime i try running the program, it gives the following error:

> couldn't recognize data in image file

But this never happens with an .png picture, which makes me wonder if .png is the only format acceptable in tkinter?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23905585/2570277) answer may help

Comment: If `tkinter` doesn't like your image file, you might want to try using the [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library. This is the most popular library to use when trying to add pictures in `tkinter`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The docstring for `PhotoImage` says](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c580a81af91af4b9df85e466f8b48c3c9c86c3df/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L4112-L4113):

```
class PhotoImage(Image):
    """Widget which can display images in PGM, PPM, GIF, PNG format."""
```

So no, PNG is not the only acceptable format. PGM, PPM, GIF, and PNG are. JPEG is not.