# How can I open an image in Python?

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, tkinter

I have looked at a lot of tutorials tried them all, but nothing seemed to work through Pygame, PIL, Tkinter. it could be because of me of course, cause Im a greenie...

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
photo = PhotoImage(file="too.jpg")
label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This has been discussed many times here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an image in Tkinter (Python 2.7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133856/how-to-add-an-image-in-tkinter-python-2-7)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct but it won't work because of the `jpg`file.

If you want to use the `PhotoImage` class you can only read read GIF and PGM/PPM images from files (see [docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)).

For other file formats you can use the [Python Imaging Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil).

Here's your example using PIL:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
image = Image.open("too.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

label = Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo  # keep a reference!
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The line `label.image = photo` is necessary if you want to avoid your image getting garbage-collected.