# Imaging problems with Python 3.6

Tags: python, image

I am creating artificial intelligence to play Chinese checkers with Python, but I can't even get an image of a board to show up!

I am using this code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
board = PhotoImage(file="board.ppm")
root.mainloop()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/GAMEKNIGHT7/Desktop/genius hour/chineseCheckersAI(genius hour).py", line 3, in <module>
    board = PhotoImage(file="board.ppm")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3539, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3495, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "board.ppm"
```

I placed the code file in the same file as the image. What happened? How can I fix it?

Comment: Well, Python is clearly not finding the file for some reason. To investigate, you may want to try printing out the result you get from calling `os.getcwd()` to make sure your working directory is what you expect. How are you running your script?

Comment: I am using the official pytho IDE to run and code my script on a mac.

Comment: Do you mean a command line terminal, or IDLE?

Comment: I am using IDLE to make my code.

Comment: Oh, and i am new to stack overflow, and i dont know how to edit my questions, so i will say it here. The error message says this at the last line: 
' _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "board.ppm"' .

Comment: There's an "edit" link just below the tags on your question (or click here: [edit]). If the traceback has changed, please update the whole thing!

Comment: So the new exception message suggests that your file doesn't contain image data that the library can read. Are your sure your PPM file is valid? That *should* be a datatype that `tkinter` can read for you, so I'd suspect the file being the problem rather than the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the following in Terminal:

```
file board.ppm
```

If it says anything with the word `ASCII` in it, that means your image is uncompressed ASCII ([NetPBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) type=3) and **Tkinter** will not like it:

```
board.ppm: Netpbm image data, size = 10 x 10, pixmap, ASCII text
```

if your file is correct, it will report `rawbits` ([NetPBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) type=6):

```
board.ppm: Netpbm image data, size = 10 x 10, rawbits, pixmap
```

---

If you want to convert from ASCII/P3 to binary/rawbits/P6, you could install **ImageMagick** with **homebrew** like this:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Then convert like this:

```
convert board.ppm -compress lossless board.ppm
```

Comment: When i ran this in terminal, neither the words ASCII or rawbits appeared:board.ppm: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 300x300, segment length 16, Exif Standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4], baseline, precision 8, 600x690, frames 3

Comment: Ok, that means your file is a JPEG image. Try changing the name to `board.jpg` and then `board = PhotoImage(file="board.jpg")`

Comment: It still returned the same thing, except it couldn't recognize the data in board.jpg

Comment: Or you could try converting to `GIF` with `sips -s format gif board.jpg --out board.gif` and then load `board.gif`

Comment: Wow! It didn't return a error! But the tkinter window is blank. I am not that good a gui coding yet.

Comment: I guess the image is too big for the window, so i somehow need to expand it. Or maybe im just not displaying the image.

Comment: OH MY... I just managed to get it right, by using the code in this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133856/how-to-add-an-image-in-tkinter. I am actually really excited. Thanks!