# Tkinter IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I am currently working on designing a UI for my project using Tkinter. I tried to insert an image using this :

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

window = Tk()
window.title("Outlier Detection using Feature Grouping")
window.configure(background = "black")

path="C:/Users/user/Desktop/od in hd/Corr"
C = tk.Canvas(window, bg="blue", height=250, width=300)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
```

and I get the error :

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/od in hd/Corr'
```

I went through the solutions in the other questions but did not understand them much as I am new to Tkinter. Why does it say that no file or directory exists? How can I insert an image to my UI? Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: Are you using python 2.7? You might need to install the PIL package to make sure it works fine. Have a look at this and the other answers in this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26440856/5028532

Comment: The error saying, the path does not exist. try inserting with correct path of your image.

Comment: If python is telling you a path doesn't exist, you can be certain it doesn't exist. Are you certain you have a file called "C:/Users/user/Desktop/od in hd/Corr"? Is it possible you have suffixes hidden and the file actually ends in .png or .gif or something?

Comment: Also, you might need to add the extention of the image. If it is a jpeg, your path would be:
path = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/od in hd/Corr.jpg"