# _tkinter.TclError: couldn't read bitmap file

Tags: python, tkinter, interface, bitmap

i don t know how to load an image from my desktop here is my code:

```
imgXBM = BitmapImage(file="./img/pylogo.xbm")

labelXBM = Label(monCadre, text="image XBM : 1 bit/pixel", font=maFonte,

bg="#b0b0ff")

labelImgXBM = Label(monCadre, image = imgXBM,font=maFonte, bg="#b0b0ff")'
```

in such attempt it show s me : `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't read bitmap file`

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133856/how-to-add-an-image-in-tkinter

Comment: Try giving the full path name of the bitmap file.  Also you need to call one of the layout functions (`pack()` or `grid()` or `place()`) on the labels.