# Tkinter Image not showing up

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm quite new to coding and I'm trying to have an image show up in a tkinter window.

However, when I run the code below there is the gap where the image should be. I am getting no error from this code as well.

```py
window2 = Toplevel()
window2.geometry("1920x1200")

Namearea = Label(window2, text="Please Name the Prebuild:")
Namearea.pack()

e = Entry(window2, width=50, borderwidth=3, bg="Light Grey", fg="black")
e.pack()

#Here is the part that is not working.
img3 = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\\Tkinter\\ComputerImage.png")
picture1 = Label(window2, image=img3)
picture1.pack()

SaveAndContinue = Button(window2, text="Save and Return to Main Menu", padx=75, pady=20, bg="Light Grey")
SaveAndContinue.pack()
```

Comment: Try the answer from josav09 for this question:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133856/how-to-add-an-image-in-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133856/how-to-add-an-image-in-tkinter)

Comment: Is this code inside a function?

Comment: Yes it is inside a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the answer from josav09 for this question:
[How to add an image in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133856/how-to-add-an-image-in-tkinter)

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

root = Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("True1.gif"))
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It says no module named 'PIL'?

Comment: Not the poster, but you will have to install it if you do not have it, through pip. The maintaned library is now called [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow).
See https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm for more details about the Tkinter PhotoImage class and PIL