# I want an image to be displayed in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a dropdown list. For each item I select from the dropdown, I was an image related to that item to show below the dropdown. I can do them separately but not sure how to put them together in tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
fruitslist = [
    "apple",
    "orange",
    "grapes",
    "banana"
]

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry('100x200')

def selc(event):
    if clicked.get() == "orange":
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("image.jpg"))
        la.configure(image=img)
        la.image = img
    else:
        print("no image")
        
la = tk.Label(root, text="hi")

clicked = tk.StringVar(root)
clicked.set(fruitslist[0])

drop = tk.OptionMenu(root, clicked, *fruitslist, command = selc)
drop.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add an image in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133856/how-to-add-an-image-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set command to the `OptionMenu` and handle all the image change logic in the function based on the selection.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

fruitslist = [
    "apple",
    "orange",
    "grapes",
    "banana"
]

app = tk.Tk()

fruits_dict = {}
for fruit_name in fruitslist:
    fruits_dict[fruit_name] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("{}.png".format(fruit_name)))

app.geometry('100x200')

variable = tk.StringVar(app)
variable.set(fruitslist[0])


def change_image(e):
    print(e)  # selected option
    # print(variable.get())  # Also you can retrieve selected option from the var
    # Change image here
    my_image.config(image=fruits_dict[e])


opt = tk.OptionMenu(app, variable, *fruitslist, command=change_image)
opt.config(width=90, font=('Helvetica', 12))
opt.pack()

my_image = tk.Label(app)
my_image.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have updated the code in my original post. I'm getting no errors but I'm also not seeing any image on the tkinter window as well. Please check?

Comment: Updated the code, make sure `fruite_name`.png exists