# How to add histogram from dataframe in tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, machine-learning, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter and am working on a GUI based on ML. I want to add a histogram plot from a dataframe into Tkinter and am stuck. This is the histogram plot:

[image]

This is part of my code

```
class Hplot:
    def __init__(self,data,master):
        self.master = master
        self.data = data

        self.window = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.window.title("Histogram Plot")
        self.window.configure(background='white')
        #self.window.resizable(False, False)

        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        self.sub = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.sub.hist(data,bins=50)
        self.sub.plot()

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, master=self.window)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        #self.canvas.draw()
```

Pls suggest the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the histogram to an image and then open it and display it in tkinter.
You can save your matplotlib image by using this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.savefig('histogram.png')
```

And if you face any problem opening and displaying the image on tkinter, that is answered [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133856/how-to-add-an-image-in-tkinter)